# Im pulling an Object tag containing a video from an API. How do I pause the video in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, api, object, video

I'm pulling a video from an API, and it's being returned in an `object` tag like the one below…

```
<object height="344" width="434">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="movie" value="http://embed.website.com/player/?id=532740&style=website">
<param name="FlashVars" value="id=532740&style=website&autostart=false">
<embed src="http://embed.website.com/player/?id=532740&style=website" allowfullscreen="true" AllowScriptAccess="always" flashvars="autostart=false" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="344" width="434" />
</object>
```

How should I go about pausing this video in Javascript on a button click?

Which element do I grab (`param name="movie"` or the entire object??) and what do I call `onClick` to pause the thing? Forgive me if this is obvious, I have only worked with frames to this point in my career. If there is anything I should be aware of in dealing with objects please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would suggest using HTML5 video tags which has native control support for play/pause.
2. If you do want to use swf, there's no common way of doing this as obviously you use a flash player to play the videos and hence you need to know if your player has a callback function to catch button event. Read the documents if any, if not you could inspect the element working in browser and do play/pause and see if there's any change in the element.
   If you see the object being marked up with attributes like play/paused, then you can use code like below. Make sure to add the ID to your object beforehand.

   function playPause(){
       if(document.getElementById('myVideo').paused){
           document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
       }
       else
       {document.getElementById('myVideo').pause();
       }
   }

And the button `<button onclick="playPause()">PLAY/PAUSE</button>`

Comment: Thanks @Godinall! Unfortunately the API I am pulling from only returns the object tags, and doesn't offer a way to get <video> or <iframe>… I added the ID through PHP and have been fiddling around with a few variations of the JS you posted, to no avail so far.

Comment: mind tell us what swf player you are using and I can have a look at that for you. why don't you use HTML5 video tags? is there a reason you have to use swf files?

Comment: I took your advice and pulled the source attribute from the object in php, using it in a video tag further down the page. Using JS controls will be no problem now. Thanks for the creative thinking